# symfony2 admingenerator many-to-many double list not working

Tags: symfony

I'm new to symfony2. I'm learning admingenerator bundle. I got the demo project AdmingeneratorIpsum ((2013-02-12.nightly.AdmingeneratorIpsum.tar.gz) ) working on my local PC. But the many-to-many double list is not working correctly. The double list for movie edit page is displayed but there is no "arrow" button to let me select actors for the movie.

BTW, does this demo project have to use the template from AdmingeneratorOldThemeBundle instead of AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle? I tried to setup a project with only  AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle and added some entities, the double list won't even displayed at all.

Could anyone give some tips on how to solve this problem? Thanks!